# Is the $n=0$ antinodal line in a double slit experiment constant loudness at all points?

Tags: waves, acoustics, interference, double-slit-experiment, superposition

If we assume a normal double-slit experiment with two speakers that produce identical sound waves, is the $n=0$ antinodal line going to have a consistent loudness wherever point on it?

As the crest and trough (antinodal) are the loudest points in a longitudinal graph and the nodal points are the quietest points, wouldn't there be a point on the $n=0$ antinodal line demonstrating constructive interference between two nodal points, hence resulting in a quiet/silent point?

Comment: It would be better if you showed which graph you mean, when you ask about "a longitudonal graph". The question isn't completely clear now, it seems to suggest that a point on an amplitude distribution graph should somehow be the average of some neighboring points on that graph (but such a self-averaging property should not be expected!)

Comment: For a single speaker, at any point, on any line, if you were really fast you could stick you microphone in the path at the nodal point and pull it out quickly and hear NO sound! But nobody is that fast so they hear something.  For 2 speakers, YES you can find null points in a 2D space where there is NO sound ... you can find these nodal points but not a line.